# Bug in OrmLite - updating record with Primary Key = 0

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given a simple poco

```
public class Model
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

this works fine ...

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN8PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;";
connectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);

using (var db = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{ db.DropAndCreateTable<Model>(); }

var model0 = new Model { ID = 0, Description = "Item Zero" };
var model1 = new Model { ID = 1, Description = "Item One" };

using (var db = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{ db.Save(model0, model1); }
```

as does this ...

```
model0.Description += " updated";
model1.Description += " updated";

using (var db = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{ 
    db.Save(model0); 
    db.Save(model1);
}
```

however, this crashes with a primary key violation exception ...

```
model0.Description += " updated again";
model1.Description += " updated again";

using (var db = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{ db.Save(model0, model1); }
```

The record with ID zero is required, as this is a lookup table to replace an existing C# enum type. This is a local copy of distributed data (that I don't control), so there's no reason to have an auto-increment key.

The issue appears to be in OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.SaveAll() - any row with id == defaultValue is assumed to be a new item, rather than an update of an existing record. The same issue occurs in the parallel async methods too.

Is there any other way to get around this issue, other than by saving each record individually (inside a transaction). It would be preferable to save all updated records for a table in one command.

Answer (score 1):

Save is a high-level API that will INSERT or UPDATE based on whether or not the Primary Key has a value. If you want to insert a default Primary Key value you can use Insert instead as seen in this [Live Example on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=3d877cee52c15b4f7cd79cabc65e2f0a):

```
public class Model
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
} 

db.DropAndCreateTable<Model>();

var model0 = new Model { ID = 0, Description = "Item Zero" };
var model1 = new Model { ID = 1, Description = "Item One" };

db.Insert(model0, model1);

var rows = db.Select<Model>();

"Inserted Rows: {0}".Print(rows.Dump());
```

Which outputs:

```
Inserted Rows: [
    {
        ID: 0,
        Description: Item Zero
    },
    {
        ID: 1,
        Description: Item One
    }
]
```

Comment: But I don't want to insert again - I'm trying to update an existing record. Calling Save() with multiple items works fine, except for when the item with ID = 0 is included. At present I can get around this by calling Save() with each item individually and it works.

Comment: @Peregrine so then you need to use `Update`, you can't use `Save()` with a default value for the primary key because it assumes the record hasn't been inserted yet.